# Is there a word to designate grammatical constructions such as "all the more since" or "as long as"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, terminology, philology

Do philologists have a single word to refer to grammatical constructions such as *all the more since* or *as long as*, or is 'grammatical construction' the most compact way to refer to those kinds of structures?

This is going to sound a bit vague, but what I'm referring to is unchangeable combinations of words that do some heavy grammatical lifting within a sentence. Please don't laugh.

Comment: I think phrases like **as long as** might be called 'complex subordinating conjunctions'.

Comment: The usual term is 'prepositional idiom'. I'd call "as long as" a compound preposition that has the comparative meaning of "provided", as in "I'll do it as long as / provided you pay me". Note that "as" and "provided" are prepositions.

Comment: Huddleston says of **as long as** something like "it's obviously not a comparative construction" but I would agree with you that it means "to the extent that" and does have a comparative sense.  I wouldn't call the second **as** a preposition, however.

Comment: Note that nobody has had anything to say about _all the more since_. This is because it's not a constituent. It's two constituents jammed together. _All the more_ has to do with some quantification in the previous clause, while _since_ is an ordinary conjunction introducing the next clause. They don't belong together just because one refers back and the other forward.

Answer (score 1):

*so* (or *as*) *long as*  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+long+as) an idiom

> - Considering the fact that; seeing as; because.
> - If it is the case that; provided that.
> - For the amount of time that (is stipulated).

Its use is that of a conjunction.

As in:  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/109979?redirectedFrom=as%20long%20as#eid118783832)

> 1953   A. L. Rowse Diary 23 Oct. (2003)    Always a public
>   humiliation so long as I can remember.

Comment: I think compound preposition is a better analysis, where the meaning is  "provided" (also a preposition).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers, everyone.

After a bit more research, to the existing answers I'd like to add the word ***LOCUTION***.

- the third definition of OED fits fairly well: *a form of expression or phraseology; a phrase, expression.*
- I realize it's not entirely relevant, but one of the definitions of the Spanish word *locución* fits exactly what I was trying to convey (see entry #3 in the [DLE of the RAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NYSj8PH)).

That being said, I see how from a grammatical standpoint *locution* can be seen as a catch-all that covers too many kinds of structures. It might need to be qualified (a certain kind of locution).

Comment: Well, you asked specifically about "all the more since" or "as long as". They are idioms, since their meaning is not derivable form the meanings of the individual words. Btw, note J Lawler's comment about "all the more since" not  being a constituent.